# How to update div in Meteor without helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, nouislider

I can I update a div using JavaScript with no problem. For example, the initial values for both divs are shown on the image on the left, and the values after clicking on the test button are shown on the right.

[image]

when I click the test button then the counter is increased by 1 and the values for the divs are changed like this:

```
var ela = document.getElementById("a");
var elb = document.getElementById("b");
$("#" + ela.id).html("new value " + ela.id + " ");
$("#" + elb.id).html("new value " + elb.id + " ");
```

So far so good, but now I would like to change the order of the divs: when the counter is even I want div a = yellow to be at the top (div b = grey at the bottom), and the other way around when the counter is uneven.

For simplicity in the example I use 2 small arrays for each of the possible orders (a,b) and (b,a) and a helper 'order' will return 1 of the 2 cases depending on the counter value (x%2 is zero or not)

Unfortunately, the result is not what I want and expected. The divs are changing position correctly, but their text is not. After the first click the counter goes from 5 to 6, so the yellow div is moving from bottom to top, but the text inside the divs is wrong, I expect 'new value a' in the yellow div that moved up, but I get 'new value b a' instead (same for other div the other way around)

Also when I inspect the divs in the console output I'm seeing strange results, Meteor seems to be confused about div ids? see the below image, the first div is both a and b, and yellow and grey at the same time ...

[image: strange console output, contradicting id's]

Does anybody know why this is? And how can I fix it?

I know I can just use helpers to get the correct text in the correct div. But my end goal is not to change the text inside divs, but instead I want to create a slider using nouislider like this:

```
var noUiSlider = require('nouislider');
var sliderHtmlElement = document.getElementById("a");
var options = {
    start: [0, 100],
    range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
    }
};
noUiSlider.create(sliderHtmlElement, options);
```

My complete test code:

```html
<template name="MyTemplate">
 {{x}}
 <br>
 <br>
 {{#each order}}
  <div class="{{label}}" id="{{label}}" 
        style="background-color: {{color}};">
            start value {{label}}
        </div>
  <br>
 {{/each}}
 <button class="test">test</button>
</template>
```

```js
var order1;
var order2;

Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function() {
 Session.set("x", 5);
 
 var or0 = [];
 or0["label"] = "a";
 or0["color"] = "yellow";

 var or1 = [];
 or1["label"] = "b";
 or1["color"] = "grey";

 order1 = [];
 order1[0] = or0;
 order1[1] = or1;
 
 order2 = [];
 order2[0] = or1;
 order2[1] = or0;
});

Template.MyTemplate.events({
 'click .test': function(event) {
  var varx = Session.get("x") + 1;
  Session.set("x", varx);
  createSliders();
 }
});

Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
 x: function() {
  return Session.get("x");
 },
 order: function() {
  if (Session.get("x") % 2 === 0) {
   return order1;
  } else {
   return order2;
  }
 }
});

function createSliders() {
 var ela = document.getElementById("a");
 var elb = document.getElementById("b");
 console.log(ela);
 console.log(elb);
 $("#" + ela.id).html("new value " + ela.id + " ");
 $("#" + elb.id).html("new value " + elb.id + " ");
}
```

Comment: So if I get this right your main problem is to create a nouislider inside a div target without a helper?

Comment: Thx for the reply. My main goal is to have a list of sliders that move up and down based on some parameter. I have no problem creating sliders, but I cannot move them up and down. Therefor I created the simple example without sliders, because the same goes for javascript generated div values: I can create them, but i cannot move it up and down without strange results (see second image that show very strange console ouput, divs are both yellow and grey at the same time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Blaze you have to explicitly import the `.css` file as well in order to get the styles applied:

```js
// no slider without css
import 'nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css'
import noUiSlider from 'nouislider'
```

Then you can easily use the Template's builtin jQuery to get a target div where nouislider will render.

Consider the following template:

```js
<template name="MyTemplate">
    <div>
        <div id="range"></div>
    </div>
    {{#if values}}
        <div>
            <span>values: </span>
            <span>{{values}}</span>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
    <button class="test">Show Slider</button>
</template>
```

Now let's render a new nouislider into the div with id `range` by clicking the button:

```js
Template.MyTemplate.events({
  'click .test': function (event, templateInstance) {
    createSliders(templateInstance)
  },
})

function createSliders (templateInstance) {
  // get the target using the template's jQuery
  const range = templateInstance.$('#range').get(0)
  noUiSlider.create(range, {
    start: [0, 100],
    range: {
      'min': [0],
      'max': [100]
    },
    connect: true
  })
}
```

Now you could also easily add some reactive data here (but avoid `Session`):

```js
Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('values', null)
})
```

... and connect it with some data. The `noUiSlider` allows you to hook into it's update event, from where you can pass the values into the state:

```js
function createSliders (templateInstance) {
  // get slider, render slider...
  // ...
  range.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    // update values, for instance use a reactive dict
    templateInstance.state.set('values', values)
  })
}
```

Render the value into the template using a helper:

```js
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
  values () {
    return Template.instance().state.get('values')
  }
})
```

Import your own `.css` files to statically style the slider like so:

```css
#range {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 14px;
}
```

or style it dynamically using jQuery's [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

---

## UPDATE: Correct rendering on updated display list

The issue you described is correct and can be reproduced. However it can also be prevented, using `Template.onRendered` to control the point when rendering may occur.

I extended the Template to the following code:

```
<template name="MyTemplate">
    {{#each sliders}}
        <div class="range">
            <div>
                <span>id:</span>
                <span>{{this.id}}</span>
            </div>
            <div id="{{this.id}}">
                {{#if ready}}{{slider this}}{{/if}}
            </div>
            {{#with values this.id}}
                <div>
                <span>values: </span>
                <span>{{this}}</span>
                </div>
            {{/with}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}

    <button class="test">Switch Sliders</button>
</template>
```

Now look inside the target div, which previously had only an id assigned. Now there is a `{{#if ready}}` flag and a function, call to `{{slider this}}`.

Now in order to render only when the DOM has initially been rendered, we need `Template.onRendered`:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state.set('ready', true)
})
```

and add it to the (updated) helpers:

```
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
  sliders () {
    return Template.instance().state.get('sliders')
  },
  values (sliderId) {
    return Template.instance().state.get('values')[sliderId]
  },
  slider (source) {
    createSliders(source.id, source.options, Template.instance())
  },
  ready() {
    return Template.instance().state.get('ready')
  }
})
```

Now we have some more issues here that need to be resolved. We only want to render if the switch changes but not if the values update. But we need the latest values in order to re-assign them as start position in the next render (otherwise the sliders would be set with the start values 0,100).

To do that we change the `onCreated` code a bit:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function () {

  // initial slider states
  const sliders = [{
    id: 'slider-a',
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, {
    id: 'slider-b',
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  },
  ]

  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('values', {}) // mapping values by sliderId
  instance.state.set('sliders', sliders)
})
```

Now if we press the switch button want a) delete all current sliders with their events etc. and b) update the `sliders` data to our new (reversed) state:

```
Template.MyTemplate.events({
  'click .test': function (event, templateInstance) {

    let sliders = templateInstance.state.get('sliders')
    const values = templateInstance.state.get('values')

    // remove current rendered sliders
    // and their events / prevent memory leak
    sliders.forEach(slider => {
      const target = templateInstance.$(`#${slider.id}`).get(0)
      if (target && target.noUiSlider) {
        target.noUiSlider.off()
        target.noUiSlider.destroy()
      }
    })

    // assign current values as
    // start values for the next newly rendered
    // sliders
    sliders = sliders.map(slider => {
      const currentValues = values[slider.id]
      if (currentValues) {
        slider.options.start = currentValues.map(n => Number(n))
      }
      return slider
    }).reverse()

    templateInstance.state.set('sliders', sliders)
  }
})
```

Because we have multiple slider values to be updated separately, we also need to change some code in the `createSlider` function:

```
function createSliders (sliderId, options, templateInstance) {
  const $target = $(`#${sliderId}`)
  const target = $target.get(0)

  //skip if slider is already in target
  if ($target.hasClass('noUi-target')) {
    return
  }

  noUiSlider.create(target, options)

  target.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    // update values by sliderId
    const valuesObj = templateInstance.state.get('values')
    valuesObj[sliderId] = values
    templateInstance.state.set('values', valuesObj)
  })
}
```

By using this approach you some advantages and some disadvantages.

- (+) pattern can be used for many similar problems
- (+) no `autorun` required
- (+) separated slider state from value state
- (-) rendering can occur more than once for a re-render, users wont notice but it wastes resources, which can be an issue on mobile.
- (-) can become overly complex on larger templates. Encapsulation of Templates is very important here.

Comment: ok good, and now put a second slider in your template that has different min max values so you can recognize them. Then try to switch their position triggered by some reactive element. It is here that strange results occur, the divs seem to switch correctly, but the content (the sliders in this case) don't switch. You can observe the same effect without sliders, see example in my original question.

Comment: Ok now I get your issue. Will check on that.

Comment: Thx for the great answer, this is exactly the solution I was looking for. I would never figured this out by myself (1.) putting the createSlider() function in a helper (2.) this helper is waiting to be run because of the ready var (3) ready var is only set true on the end of onRender template so the divs are ready and loaded correctly available for sliders. I also learned to make better use of Template.instance(), and also +1 for the little check if slider already exists (I was doing try/catch when creating a slider, but I like your check for class 'noUi-target' better)

Comment: btw I asked a second question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340006/nouisliders-dissapear-when-moving-them-on-some-event , it is about the same nouislider list, but this time I tried to add non nouislider elements to the list, but failed... :(