# nouisliders dissapear when moving them on some event

Tags: javascript, meteor, nouislider

This is very much related to my first question about nousliders here: [How to update div in Meteor without helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283876/how-to-update-div-in-meteor-without-helper) (this title was not well chosen, because it was not about avoiding helpers)

The answer provided by Jankapunkt works very well, for example I can have 4 sliders, and reordering works without loosing slider states like min/max like this:

[image: switching slider works ok]

now I want some of the elements to be non-sliders, for example change 1 to a dropdown:

[image]

but when I click the switch button, 1 slider dissapears (the one that moves to the dropdown spot), and I get an error in console:

```
Exception in template helper: Error: noUiSlider (11.1.0): create requires a single element, got: undefined
```

I don't understand why adding if/else makes any difference ... the slider helper is waiting for ready {{#if ready}}...{{/if}} so it should work ? anyone understand why it doesn't ? and how to fix it ?

template onCreated looks now like this:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  const sliders = [{
    id: 'slider-a',
    prio: 1,
    type: "NumberRange",
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, {
    id: 'slider-b',
    prio: 2,
    type: "NumberRange",
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, {
    id: 'dropdown-c',
    prio: 3,
    type: "Dropdown"
  }, {
    id: 'slider-d',
    prio: 4,
    type: "NumberRange",
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, ]

  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('values', {}) // mapping values by sliderId
  instance.state.set('sliders', sliders)
})
```

and template now looks like this, there is an if else statement to show Dropdown or NumberRange (slider):

```
<template name="MyTemplate">
{{#each sliders}}
    <div class="range">
        <div>
            <span>id:</span>
            <span>{{this.id}}</span>
        </div>
        {{#if $eq type 'Dropdown'}}
            <select id="{{this.id}}" style="width: 200px;">
                <option value="">a</option>
                <option value="">b</option>
                <option value="">c</option>
            </select>
        {{else if $eq type 'NumberRange'}}
            <div id="{{this.id}}">
                {{#if ready}}{{slider this}}{{/if}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#with values this.id}}
            <div>
                <span>values: </span>
                <span>{{this}}</span>
            </div>
        {{/with}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
<button class="test">Switch Sliders</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be aware of the situation:

- You are mixing classic ui rendering (the sliders) with Blaze rendering (the dropdown). This will bring you a lot of design problems and the solution below is more a hack than a clean appraoch using Blaze's API
- Since your components are not only sliders anymore, you should rename your variables. Otherwise it is hard for a foreign person to decode your variable's context.
- Your dropdown has currently no values saved, switching the button resets the dropdown.
- You can't destroy a `noUiSlider` on the dropdown when hitting the switch button, causing the error you described above.

Therefore I want to give you some advice on restructuring your code first.

#### 1. Renaming variables

You can use your IDE's refactoring functionality to easily rename all your variable names. If you don't have such functionality in your IDE / editor I highly suggest you to start your search engine to get one.

Since you have more input types than sliders, you should use a more generic name, like `inputs` which indicates a broader range of possible types.

There should also be a `value` entry on your dropdown, do be able to restore the last selection state when re-rendering:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function () {

  const inputs = [{
    id: 'slider-a',
    prio: 1,
    type: 'NumberRange',
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, {
    id: 'slider-b',
    prio: 2,
    type: 'NumberRange',
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  }, {
    id: 'dropdown-c',
    prio: 3,
    type: 'Dropdown',
    value: '', // default none
  }, {
    id: 'slider-d',
    prio: 4,
    type: 'NumberRange',
    options: {
      start: [0, 100],
      range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
      },
      connect: true
    }
  },]

  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('values', {}) // mapping values by sliderId
  instance.state.set('inputs', inputs)
})
```

Now you also have to rename your helpers and the template helper calls:

```
<template name="MyTemplate">
    {{#each inputs}}
    ...
    {{/each}}
</template>

Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
  inputs () {
    return Template.instance().state.get('inputs')
  },
  ...
})
```

#### 2. Handle multiple input types on switch event

You also should rename your variables in the switch event. Furhtermore, you need to handle different input types here. Dropdowns have no `.noUiSlider` property and they also receive not an array but a string variable as value:

```
'click .test': function (event, templateInstance) {

  let inputs = templateInstance.state.get('inputs')
  const values = templateInstance.state.get('values')

  // remove current rendered inputs
  // and their events / prevent memory leak
  inputs.forEach(input => {

    if (input.type === 'Dropdown') {
      // nothing to manually remove
      // Blaze handles this for you
      return
    }

    if (input.type === 'NumberRange') {
      const target = templateInstance.$(`#${input.id}`).get(0)
      if (target && target.noUiSlider) {
        target.noUiSlider.off()
        target.noUiSlider.destroy()
      }
    }
  })

  // assign current values as
  // start values for the next newly rendered
  // inputs
  inputs = inputs.map(input => {
    const currentValues = values[input.id]

    if (!currentValues) {
      return input
    }

    if (input.type === 'Dropdown') {
      input.value = currentValues
    }

    if (input.type === 'NumberRange') {
      input.options.start = currentValues.map(n => Number(n))
    }

    return input
  }).reverse()

  templateInstance.state.set('inputs', inputs)
},
```

#### 3. Correct rendering / update display list

Now comes the problem of mixing Blaze rendering with classic DOM updates: until this point you will run into an error. This is mainly because *now* our `createSliders` function will expect a `div` element with a certain id at the place where the dropdown has been rendered *before* the switch has been pressed. It won't be there because the Blaze render invalidation will not be finished at this point.

Fixing this using `autorun` in `onCreated` or `onRendered` will easily increase complexity or even messes up your code. A simpler solution is to use a short timeout here:

```
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
  // ...
  slider (source) {
    const instance = Template.instance()
    setTimeout(()=> {
      createSliders(source.id, source.options, instance)
    }, 50)
  },
  // ...
})
```

#### 4. Bonus: saving state of dropdown

In order to save the state of the dropdown, you need to hook into it's `change` event. You therefore need to assign it a class to map the event independently of the `id`:

```
 <select id="{{this.id}}" class="dropdown" style="width: 200px;">...</select>
```

For which now you can create an event:

```
'change .dropdown'(event, templateInstance) {
  const $target = templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget)
  const value = $target.val()
  const targetId = $target.attr('id')
  const valuesObj = templateInstance.state.get('values')
  valuesObj[targetId] = value
  templateInstance.state.set('values', valuesObj)
}
```

Now you have saved your current dropdown value but in order to restore it in the next render, you need to extend the `options` in the html:

```
<select id="{{this.id}}" class="dropdown" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="a" selected="{{#if $eq this.value 'a'}}selected{{/if}}">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected="{{#if $eq this.value 'b'}}selected{{/if}}">b</option>
    <option value="c" selected="{{#if $eq this.value 'c'}}selected{{/if}}">c</option>
</select>
```

This should now also display the last selected state of the dropdown.

#### Summary

- You can use this pattern to include even more input components.
- Be aware, that mixing Blaze rendering with traditional DOM manipulations can increase the complexity of your code a lot. Same applies for many other rendering systems / libraries / frameworks out there.
- The `setTimeout` solution should be the last approach to be used when other approaches are even less feasible.
- Variable and method naming should always represent their context. If the context changes -> rename / refactor variables and methods.
- *Please next time post the full code here again.* Your other post might get updated or deleted and the full code won't be accessible here anymore, making it hard for others to find a good solution.

Comment: Adding the timeout worked, so I marked this as a correct answer. But I don't like it though (you mention yourself it is more a hack, and last resort). I guess I should not mix classic UI and blaze, but because I really want to use the nouisliders I will go with the timeout for now.